# Is syncing my cloud to SSD recommended?

Tags: sync

I've just replaced my laptop's HDD to a Crosair SSD Force LE.

I want to setup my InSync client (Google Drive sync) to sync my files to it, but due to the constant writes, I was wondering if it's a good idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how much data you're actually talking about. Or if that's a problem. You might be being risk-averse when no real risk exists.

If you're adding  hundreds of gigabytes of new data to your drive  that's going to use a lot of download and writing. If you're adding the odd 5MB photo and 200KB spreadsheet that's only going to be responsible for that much write. You can use tools like `iotop` to monitor write totals, intensity, etc.

And how much is your SSD good for? Many reputable manufacturers publish stats on write intensity and durability. Looking at yours:

```
DWPD (Drive Writes Per Day) : 0.23  
  TBW (Total Bytes Written) : 60TB
```

These don't strike me as particularly great spec but **you** have to weigh the balance between:

- The likelihood **your** write intensity will lower the lifespan of your drive while you use it.
- How much will replacing it cost when it needs replacing?
- How much value **you** derive from getting a synced drive.

Personally speaking, all drives fail eventually and that's often not from wear. Wear issues tend to be non-catastrophic (the writeable area just gets lower). I'd enable SMART monitoring, and use the hardware I have and not worry too much about normal use.

Comment: Thank you. Where did you get these numbers? And what does 0.23 mean?

Comment: @PenguinCSC They are the specs for your SSD.

Comment: I stuck "Crosair SSD Force LE" (even with the spello) and it gave me [the manufacturer's page](http://www.corsair.com/en-gb/force-series-le-240gb-sata-3-6gbs-ssd) with that information (and more). 0.23 drive writes per day means it's rated to allow you to overwrite the *entire* drive once every 4-5 days.  As I say, unless you're shovelling around *hundreds* of gigabytes a day, you'll likely have upgraded or replaced the drive before it ever becomes a real issue.

Comment: And even if you are overwriting one bit of the drive more than that, if that one section wears out, a modern SSD will just move that data to another physical location and disable the worn one. Capacity gets slightly smaller but it keeps on working.